# Open external web-page with using htaccess and php

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

if request to my site goes like:

```
my1stdomain.com/request-1/  
my1stdomain.com/any-another-request/
```

it should open web-pages:

```
my2nddomain.com/folder/request-1.php  
my2nddomain.com/folder/any-another-request.php
```

I put php file in the web-root of my1stdomain.com with name referer.php

and it looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (html|php)$
RewriteCond /home3/juraj1/public_html/referer.php -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ /referer.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and referer.php looks like:

```
<?
    $login=preg_replace('/\//i','',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    $html=file_get_contents('http://my2nddomain.com/folder/'.$login.'.html');

    echo $html;
?>
```

but it returns only html content without css styles and images

Can you please help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the HTML files on my2nddomain.com link to the css files/images in a relative way, like `<img src="images/picture.jpg" />`. But since this image does not exist on my1stdomain.com, the browser doesn't find it.

**Solution 1:**
Link to all images/css files with an absolute path, like `<img src="http://my2nddomain.com/images/picture.jpg" />`

**Solution 2**
Add the `<base>` tag to the HTML head of all the files on my2nddomain.com like this: `<base href="http://my2nddomain.com" />`. This can be achieved by changing the HTML on the fly like `$html = str_replace('</head>','<base href="http://my2nddomain.com" /></head>',$html);`

There are also other solution with rewriting every request to a css file/image on your 1st server to the corresponding file of the 2nd server, but this will be more complicated.